# Active item issue with Ext.carousel in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, carousel

i have created Ext.carousel view with sencha touch. 
i have set it property **"activeItem: 2"** to display 3rd item when view is load. 
it works fine, but my issues is when view is loaded, it display 1st item for bit time then after 3rd item is display. 
i want redirect view on directly on 3rd item. 
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this may be a dumb question but if the 3rd item is always the first to display, why wouldn't you just move the 3rd item to the 1st position.

Comment: yes,i know it very well, but there is a reason behind doing like that.

Comment: is carousel a root view or is it being pushed afterwards? If it is root view then you would directly see third item w/o first item even, for a sec. And if carousel is pushed afterwards, then I'd suggest to set config option `activeItem` before actually pushing the view.

Comment: actually, my root view is navigation view with container in which i have loaded carousel view as a child controller, so carousel view is on root view. but, it takes little bit time to load 3rd item first.